# Why DocuSign draft envelopes not visible under draft?

Tags: docusignapi

There are two issues I am facing for draft envelopes:

1. Envelope with status `created` i.e. `draft` created through REST API not visible under users draft folder but create envelope REST API request returns success with created envelope id and path for envelope
2. Draft envelope created directly in `DocuSign` gets displayed for sometime under draft but once after browser refresh that draft request somehow gets removed from draft folder.

Here is how I am doing that directly in `DocuSign`:

- Create new envelope request

[image]

- Save and close as draft

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that it appears to be a bug:

1. Create an envelope in the web app
2. Add a document to the envelope
3. Click Actions / Save and Close

Result:
The draft envelope appears in the drafts folder for a minute or two. Refreshing the drafts folder page then shows no entries.

I've submitted internal bug report NDSESEND-3161.

You can ask your DocuSign customer support rep to add your company's information to the bug report.

#### Update Oct 28

This bug has been confirmed as a release_blocker (EC-3808). It had also been caught by DocuSign's automated tests. It will be fixed on the developer (demo) environment and will block the Nov release until it is fixed.

It has already been fixed in the stage environment. (Stage is an internal environment. It precedes the Developer environment.)

#### Update Oct 29 8:30 AM GMT

The bug should be fixed on the developer (demo) environment by **Oct 29, 9am Pacific time.**

Please post a comment at that time to confirm that the bug has been fixed. Thank you.

Comment: This is happening only in development environment.

Comment: @Kaishu, please check the bug at 9am Pacific time today or later and post a comment whether it is fixed or not. Thank you, Larry.

Comment: Tested in demo environment and now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to envelopes via the API, you didn't share your code, but here are a few possibilities:

1. Different account and/or different user. The API is using a token that uniquely identifies the user. There's also an account GUID in the API endpoint that uniquely identifies the account. If these don't match the one you manually used to log in the browser - you'll not see the envelopes in there.
2. Confusion between developer and production accounts. You may have two environments. Make sure it's account-d and demo.docusign.net URLs if you use the developer account.
3. Envelope is not in draft. Maybe it was set to another status other than "created" (which is what it's called from the API).
4. Envelope was not created because of error. The most likely option is that you had an error in the API call and didn't realize it. It can be because you didn't properly provide at least one document, at least one recipient and the subject message for your envelope.

Comment: We have DocuSign service integration with blanket consent. Using user consent we send request to selected user's draft with status 'created'. Above request I am sending in sandbox i.e. development environment. If I load envelope request through DocuSign api explorer, it says envelope status 'created' everything looks good.  This is not only through REST api call but for envelope directly created in DocuSign having same issue as described in question

Comment: I assume "blanket consent" means for all users, is it possible you have two different users?

Comment: No - that is not the case

Comment: Same thing happening for draft envelopes created directly in DocuSign. After browser refresh, draft requests getting removed from user's draft.

Comment: you may want to reach to support for non API issues, for the API the draft envelopes should be there if your API call was made succshefully. Please share your code for further help with the API.